# What features are seasonal and can I access them outside the season?

Tags: killing-floor

It seems the game has special modes for some events: summer, Christmas, Halloween and maybe more? What content am I missing out on and can I force the game to let me use that seasonal content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several events in the game:

- Christmas Event
- Summer Event
- Halloween Event
- Potato Sack Event with the Portal Map and special Vendor items

Those Events are enabled and disabled during the seasons via a Steam patch. So it is not just a matter of a console command, you miss the physical data since it get's erased after the event. There are some mods out there that let you enable those Events, but they are all very outdated and discontinued.

Use this one on your own risk:

- http://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/showthread.php?t=49399

Please be aware that KF is VAC protected and I do not know how this may affect your game. KF does support mods though, so it *should* be safe to use if not prevented by some patch or update that makes this mod incompatible.

What you "miss out on" is simply that the Zeds have a different skin and look like clowns and other carnival related stuff during the summer, more scary during helloween and like christmas elves, snowman and reindeers during winter.

During the potato sack event all Zeds look the same, but you can earn a special achievement, "The Golden Potato" if you manage to buy a special weapon from the vendor, which costs 80.000 BP, and use that to unlock a special door.

For each seasonal event there is a set of achievements available which can only be earned during those events.

Comment: When are these events held?

Comment: Those events are always near the Steam Sale Events, the Potato Sack Event mostly around April 1st. It is not a fixed date.

Comment: Is there any sort of notification for when these events start?

Comment: Yes, Steam downloads a patch :D and sometimes you get a popup if you did not disable them. Also, it is in the News: http://store.steampowered.com/news/?appids=1250